# Реализация периодической печати

Tags: перевод, грамматика

In my text book there is a copy of a "перечень" at a train and one bullet on the list is:
"Реализация периодической печати".

"Реализация" the проводник will be able to sell or borrow the passenger a newspaper or magazine?

What falls into the scope of: "периодической печати"? ((weekly/monthly) magazines/daily newspapers?)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of textbook are you using, that teaches you all this bureaucratese?

Comment: I believe it's just an excerpt from the Russian Railways conduсtor's handbook

Comment: I noticed someone docked points off because I asked the questions related to this topic. It is not my fault that the authors put that into the text book and that it is not possible to decode all the wordings by using a regular "slovar" or the machine translation. "We" are using www.ruslan.co.uk, the R3 ed., p.13

Comment: @Ева I meant no offence, just genuinely curious. I guess getting familiar with Russian bureaucratese may indeed be useful as part of an advanced course.

Comment: This forum is the best ever. I am able to pick up a lot about Russian language, traditions, get new insights, learn new aspects (by getting many different views) and also learn about every day life, what is the norm and what has been the norm in Russian language. Things I would never be able to pick up elsewhere for this I am very grateful. This is possible because you are good people, and smart people. That is what makes this forum unique and that is why I like to come back. It makes my Russian language learning fun and keeps me going.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Реализация* in this context is nominalized *реализовать* which is officialese for *продавать*, "to sell".

*Периодическая печать* is, literally, "periodicals": newspapers and magazines, but this would also usually include puzzle books, soft cover novels, that kind of stuff.

This clause means that the conductor has to offer some print media for sale for you to read during your journey.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the small but important details.